# Python keeps giving keyboardInterrupt when I try to end a program that isn't working, and split function isn't working properly

Tags: python, split, keyboardinterrupt

I'm trying to make a python program that will translate to a custom language from an input that is given. I had it working with a gender system, for example **the man** is **de mno** while **the woman** is **di felio**. I then moved on to making a system where **with the man** becomes **aile mno** instead of **ail de mno**. I'm not too good with Python, so for me in theory the way I did this should work.

The way I thought it would work is that generally a preposition comes before an article and noun, so if the translator hits a preposition, it checks ahead to the noun to see whether it is female or male and changes based on that (which I successfully made it do). It then adds all the characters to `prepo`. If it hits 'the', then it checks back to see if there is a preposition before. If there is, the `pass` function runs so it doesn't add any translation for 'the', but if there isn't it checks ahead for gender and runs as usual.

The main code is in the `elif word in Preposition:` and `elif word == 'the':` lines.

The end goal would be to turn **The man is with the woman** into **De mno aili felio** instead of **De mno ail di felio**.

I don't know if the code is actually working because when I run it and type anything with 'the' other than 'the' by itself, the code stops running but I can still type things and enter them. When I end the program it says `keyboardInterrupt`.

A fix for that problem and a solution for how I would go about doing it would really be appreciated.

```
import string

NounM = {
    'man': 'mno',
    'rock': 'lehr'
}

NounF = {
    'woman': 'felio',
    'chair': 'poen'
}

Verb = {
    'sit': 'colt',
    'is': 'ne',
    'are': 'sey',
    'was': 'sai'
}

Preposition = {
    'on': 'mit',
    'with': 'ail'
}

Pronoun = {
    'he': 'tse',
    'she': 'se',
    'i': 'ile',
    'me': 'men',
    'they': 'er',
    'it': 'ze'
}

Adjective = {
    'happy': 'kliony',
    'sad': 'probo',
    'good': 'klio',
    'bad': 'pro'
}

Article = {
    'that': 'arei',
    'those': 'sie'
}


def translate():
    sentence = input('Enter the sentence to turn into your custom language! ')
    split = sentence.split()
    translated_list = []
    translated_sentence = ''
    
    for index, word in enumerate(split):
        char = ''
        for a in string.punctuation:
            if str(a) in word:
                char = a
        if word in NounM:
            translated_sentence += NounM[word]
        elif word in NounF:
            translated_sentence += NounF[word]
        elif word in Verb:
            translated_sentence += Verb[word]
        elif word in Preposition:
            translated_sentence += Preposition[word]
            try:
                c = split[index + 1]
                while c not in NounM and c not in NounF:
                    a = 2
                    c = split[index + a]
                    a += 1
                if c in NounM:
                    translated_sentence += 'e'
                elif c in NounF:
                    translated_sentence += 'i'
            except IndexError:
                pass
        elif word in Pronoun:
            translated_sentence += Pronoun[word]
        elif word in Adjective:
            translated_sentence += Adjective[word]
        elif word in Article:
            translated_sentence += Article[word]
        elif word == 'the':
            try:
                c = split[index - 1]
                while c not in Preposition:
                    a = 2
                    c = split[index - a]
                    a += 1
                f = len(c)
                if c[f] == 'e' or c[f] == 'i':
                    pass
            except IndexError:
                c = split[index + 1]
                while c not in NounM and c not in NounF:
                    a = 2
                    c = split[index + a]
                    a += 1
                if c in NounM:
                    translated_sentence += 'de'
                elif c in NounF:
                    translated_sentence += 'di'
                else:
                    pass
        elif word == 'a':
            c = split[index + 1]
            while c not in NounM and c not in NounF:
                a = 2
                c = split[index + a]
                a += 1
            if c in NounM:
                translated_sentence += 'es'
            elif c in NounF:
                translated_sentence += 'en'
            else:
                pass
        else:
            translated_sentence += word
        word += str(char)
        word += ' '
        for i in translated_sentence:
            translated_list += i
        translated_list += str(char)
        translated_list += ' '
        translated_sentence = ''

    leng = len(translated_list) - 2
    final = translated_list[leng]
    if final in string.punctuation:
        translated_list.remove(final)

    translated_sentence = ''
    for i in translated_list:
        translated_sentence += i

    if final in string.punctuation:
        translated_sentence += final

    print(translated_sentence)
    other_translate = input('Would you like to translate another sentence? y/n ')
    if other_translate == 'y':
        translate()


translate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this bug is the code is stuck in a while loop forever. The bug is in here:

```
while c not in Preposition:
    a = 2
    c = split[index - a]
    a += 1
```

In case the input sentence doesn't have 'on' or 'with'. This loop will iterate forever.

You should add a break case for this loop, adding these codes for example:

```
while c not in Preposition:
    a = 2
    c = split[index - a]
    a += 1
    if (index - a) < 0:
        break
```

Hope it works!